# Using external DLL's in C# COM-DLL project for MS-Access usage

Tags: c#, json, ms-access, dll, naudio

The user's main application is ms-access (with ms-sql server). Ton of code in vba.
One of the main features i have to manifest is controlling my client's voip telephony. My plan is to make a COM DLL that the ms-access can use.

As of now, i've managed to write a C# project (vs2019 .net framework) that handles the voip pbx well, using json, and do all missions necessary, such as invoking calls, sending sms, get calls list, recodings list, get recordings wav files and convert them to mp3. I use Newtopsoft.Json and NAudio.Lame.

BUT it only works as a standalone .net project or exe.
As a COM DLL (class library) - ms-access can handle and use it UNTIL it gets to the part where the code uses ANY external dll's functionality - and it crashes (with newtonsoft) or just not working (with naudio), although the dll's are in the working folder.

I know i have to found a way to make these external dll's to work under the office (32bit) enviroment.
I was trying and guessing many code samples for a couple of days. I tried to follow the Assembly.Load/From/File examples to dynamically load and include the dll's, but i failed to assimilate it in my code or even to understand it enough.

I hope i'll get a solution here.
Thanks :)

Comment: How about turning the software into an API/service that you call with a com dll?

Comment: thankx for your reply. i now looking for several alternatives :)

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I am able to create a COM object for use with Access. External library code (in my case Newton soft) for serializing data works just fine when that class code is used as a COM object from Access.
You don't mention if the other libraries are managed code, or external win32 .dll?  I have however used un-managed .dll’s with a .net COM object, and then have consumed that from MS-access.
The only issue would be in project explorer is to ensure that you have a copy local setting = true for the external referenced .net .dll libraries. (And that is the default, so I am sure you do.
The next issue of course is of course is there any use of configuration files? (app.config) etc.? The reason for this of course that since your application is being launched with msaccess.exe, then the config and settings will be assumed to be in the office install folder, and not the local application. As a result, it not all so practical to move/copy those app.config files to the office folder where msaccess.exe resides. And the config file name will not only have to be in the same folder, but also named.

Msaccess.exe.config.

In place of

YourDotNet.exe.config

Now of course, if you build your project as a .net exec? Well then of course any config settings (application ones, not user) will be placed in this config file, and of course that file will have to be placed in the same folder as the .exe file.

So, one might add a “test” function (any function is a method of that class) to the class that you test/call from VBA to ensure that such settings are being seen and read (if you are using any settings).

Eg:

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config"

So, return that to access and display this result.

The other issue is of course to FORCE your project to x86. I would not use “any” CPU. While this “may” work, since you are using access x32, then I would force compile your .net class to x86 as opposed to “any” CPU. This would also spit out some errors in case some of the external assemble(ies) are compared to a particular bit size and thus x86 settings will result in your class not consuming some of the external .net .dll’s.

Now you “note” that your project works as an .exe, and then “sort of” works as a class and “.dll” registered as a COM.

However, you don’t mention how you are “flipping” this from an .exe to a class, or do you simply have a .net “test” project that you run as an .exe, and it of course has a reference to that class .dll. And you NOT using “COM” for this testing.

If your test.exe program can use that external assembly?

Then I would create a test2 project, but this time around do NOT reference the assembly (as .net), but try using .net CreateObject(). (I think c# has this choice – vb.net certainly does).

So you could try + use a CreateObject() in this .net test sample, and thus test from .net as COM.

So this test .net program (one that has NOT referenced the assembly) would a  intermediate test before you jump all the way into ms-access + VBA test code.

However, I would first test/check if an app.config file is being used here, since as noted when you flip to a COM object, and then create a instance of that object in Access/VBA?
Then the config file will NOT be used. You can in .net code force/change the app.config file in that running assembly, and I can’t seem to find my code example that does this. But I am not going to dig too hard until such time we confirm that you are using app.exe.config file here.

## Edit

Out of cuirous, I googled naudio. It is managed code. So, that library should work just fine. If that project is compiled as "ANY CPU", you COULD try re-compile as x86, and also re-compile your test program as x86. Then when you create a COM object, then again compile that as x86.

As noted, I do quite a bit of COM stuff for ms-access, and I have without issue used Newtonsoft (for jason serializing/de-serializing) as a COM object that is consumed by ms-access.

And given that naudio is managed code then I don't see why it would be an issue. Any other 3rd party .dll's you using here? As a quick test, I would set all projects to x86. You seem to "mention" that "some" of the COM object works, but just not all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Albert for your elaborate answer.
i wasn't clear - i did a stand alone exe project and it worked fine.
I made a separate COM project and it failed with access.
Due to your answer that you experienced no problems as i did with COM for Access (tears in my eyes... :P), i'm quite suspicious i did not enclosed and define the COM well, and made some error in the process. i'll do some isolated testing project to figure out where i was wrong.

Comment: NewtionSoft (jason lib) is fine and I used it many times from .net as a COM object in Access. I would create a test .net project to consume that class. get it all working and THEN try that separate class as a COM object. This approach will allow you to test + get the class working much faster, and all testing and dev will occur in VS. So create a new class only project in .net, put whatever you need in that class project, and then consume it from another "main" .exe .net project. Once this all works just fine, then try the class as a COM from Access.